# How to grep and cut at the same time

Tags: bash, grep, cut

Having trouble with grepping and cutting at the same time
I have a file `test.txt`.
Inside the file is this syntax

```
File: blah.txt Location: /home/john/Documents/play/blah.txt
File: testing.txt Location /home/john
```

My command is `./delete -r (filename)`, say filename is `blah.txt`.

How would i search `test.txt` for `blah.txt` and cut the `/home/john/Documents/play/blah.txt` out and put it in a variable

Comment: Your question is confusing - do you want to store the file path '/home/john/Documents/play/blah.txt' in a variable, and that text is a line in test.txt?

Comment: yes i want to store the location in a variable..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
grep -P "^File: blah\.txt Location: .+" test.txt | cut -d: -f3
```

Comment: @Johnathon: you are supposed to accept an answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: You can remove the cat with `grep -P "^File: blah\.txt Location: .+" test.txt | cut -d: -f3` You rarely need the `cat` command.

Answer (score 5):

Prefer always to involse as less as possible external command for your task.

You can achive what you want using **single** *awk* command:

```
awk '/^File: blah.txt/ { print $4 }' test.txt
```

Comment: Excellent answer. One command with no piping, and it much easier to maintain than cut/grep combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ;)

```
filename=$(grep 'blah.txt' test.txt | grep -oP 'Location:.*' | grep -oP '[^ ]+$')
./delete $filename
```